# How to return right dynamic type by union type argument

Tags: typescript, extends, union-types

I wonder why this error was reported.
please help me how to fix the error.

here is the code

```
type A = 'a'
type B = 'b'

type returnA = 'type_a'
type returnB = 'type_b'

function useFunc<T extends A | B>(type: T = 'a' as T) {

    function resolveSomeByType(): T extends A ? returnA : returnB {
        if (type == 'a') {
            // type error:  Type 'a' is not assignable to type 'T extends "a" ? "type_a" : "type_b"'.
            return 'type_a' as returnA
        } else {
            // type error:  Type 'b' is not assignable to type 'T extends "a" ? "type_a" : "type_b"'.
            return 'type_b' as returnB
        }
    }

    return { resolveSomeByType }
}
```

and i wanna expect a right type to be return

```
const { resolveSomeByType } = useFunc('a')
const result = resolveSomeType() // expect result 'type_a' by argument 'a' or 'type_b' by argument 'b'
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like cheating the compiler and moving the signature into an overload: https://tsplay.dev/NnbJ6N

Comment: @caTS THX!  your code is passed, but I just want to know why  the error happened.

Comment: See the answers to the linked questions for more information.  For your particular example I'd be more inclined to use an indexed access type as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvGvYw), since the input is just a string literal, and TS handles such generic indexing operations more easily than it handles generic if/else chains.